# Is using std::move to dump a member acceptable design?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, factory, move

Say I have a class `C` the only purpose of which is to fill up a container `con_m` of some type that is a member of `C`. So `C` possesses methods to fill up `con_m` in a specific manner. After `C` has filled up `con` I no longer need `C`, so I want to dump `con_n` into another variable. But `C` is actually a functor in the sense that `con_m` can only be filled up incrementally, so cannot be a object local to the filling function. Also the implementation should be hidden to the user, so he does not need to call `std::move` on the function returning `con_m`.

```
template <class container_type> class C {

public:

  template <class T> void fill_some_more(const T &t) {
    // do stuff with t filling con_m by another increment
  }

  container_type dump_container() { return std::move(con_m); }

  container_type con_m;
};

int main() {
    C<std::vector<int>> c;
  while (some_condition) {
      c.fill_some_more(some_int);
  }
  auto con = c.dump_container();
}
```

Is this an appropriate use of `std::move`?

Comment: It sounds like methods of `C` might be better off as standalone functions that take the container as a parameter. You won't have a problem of digging the container out of the class if it's not a member in the first place.

Comment: Seems to depend on whether your move-constructor leaves the source object in the desired state

Comment: I would say no. In general the move constructor is not required to leave the container empty.

Comment: Don't think it is a good idea because of opaqueness of purpose. Other people are going to look at it, raise an eyebrow, and either figure out what you are up to or make horrible, crash-inducing assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

> Also the implementation should be hidden to the user

Moving the contents of an object is *not* an implementation detail; it's part of what the function is doing. By moving the contents of the object, you make it so that the object has lost its contents, and therefore code that gets called later needs to respect that fact.

The reason why the C++ standards committee made it so that you had to use `std::move` a lot explicitly was so that people reading your code would be able to know what's going on. If a person sees `c.dump_container()`, they will probably assume that the dumping happened via copy. If they see `std::move(c).dump_container()`, and if they see that they *cannot* call it on an lvalue reference, then it's very clear to everyone involved what the state of `c` will be afterwards.

Movement should be explicit.

Of course, as Igor pointed out in the comments, this whole thing could be avoided if these were free functions that acted on a user-provided container, rather than having to have the container be a member of some type.